# Вывод иерархии MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как вывести такую иерархию и количество:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как-то по типу вот так:

[image: Сертификаты 21 Сертификаты - Мужские сертификаты 17 Сертификаты - Мужские сертификаты - Сертификат на поход в барбершоп 4 Сертификаты - Мужские сертификаты - Сертификат на .... 3 Сертификаты - Мужские сертификаты - Сертификат на .... 10 Сертификаты - Женские сертификаты 14 Сертификаты - Женские сертификаты - Сертификат на поход в СПА 6 Сертификаты - Женские сертификаты - Сертификат на .... 3 Сертификаты - Женские сертификаты - Сертификат на .... 5]

Comment: Распишите Ваш вопрос подробнее. На каком языке программирования хотите реализовать вывод. По какому принципу происходи отношение сертификата к мужскому или женскому?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, SQL в MS SQL.
Распределения как такового нет, просто для сертификата который относится к женскому путь будет /2/x, а к мужскому - /1/x

Comment: версия-то какая?